# Vhost works in Chrome but not in firefox? (XAMPP)

Tags: apache, xampp, vhosts

My vhost config appears to work in Chrome but not in Firefox?

```
127.0.0.1 dev.test.local

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:\xampp\htdocs\12345-test\public"
    ServerName dev.test.local
    ServerAlias dev.test.local
    <Directory "D:\xampp\htdocs\12345-test\public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Chrome result: reachable

Firefox result: shows index of /

Restarting XAMPP and going to my domain on Firefox doesn't work, If i open it in Chrome it works and then also starts working in Firefox? heh?

Comment: When you load `/` Firefox shows a directory index and Chrome doesn't? That's what `Options Indexes` is meant for so I guess Chrome is doing something wrong. What does Chrome display? What are you expecting?

Comment: Chrome shows the backend page as I expect it to but Firefox shows an index. Strange thing is I have this setup on my other PC at work (the vhost I mean) and only use Chrome there but there it doesn't work at all... It's just a laravel project I already checked the index.php and it seems fine, when index is shown it doesn't reach it obviously

Comment: So you want to load `index.php` then. Nothing in the settings you've shared specifically configures that. Perhaps you had it earlier and Chrome is showing a cached version. You need to add [DirectoryIndex index.php](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex).

Comment: Well sure but shouldn't it already be specified in Apache at <IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php? Because it is.

Comment: I didn't know that, you've just mentioned it for the first time. Is mod_dir itself enabled? Have you cleared Firefox cache?

Comment: Now that you mention it I did recently run CCleaner which cleaned all caches and now it does appear to work properly in FF again, I just wonder if this would also fix it for me on the other pc, but I don't have access to it right now.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same error, finally I found this solution

After xampp vhost setting, then system32 localhost url register is needed.

Please check this url.

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/configure-virtual-host-on-windows-10-for-wordpress/

Sometimes, you can't edit system file because of non-permission.

On that case, please check this url.

https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/you-dont-have-permission-to-save-in-this-location.html

This url explains how to give full control to administrators on specific folders on system.